# Heroku keeps on using Postgres instead of MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql, heroku

I have a Java application that uses Hibernate. It's configured to write to a MySQL db. I can say that I configured it correctly because when I run it on my local machine `(on Tomcat and Jetty)`, tables are created in my local db.

However, when I deploy it to Heroku, the tables are not created. Heroku logs:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'po
stgres://zzz:zzz@ec2-111-11-111-11.compute-1.a
mazonaws.com:5432/zzz'
```

Logs

Why is Heroku connecting to this db instead of using my configurations?

Additional info: App is deployed. It's just that the db tables are not created.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to establish a MySQL connection to a Postgres database.  Either use a Postgres driver instead, or use a MySQL database.

Look here for MySQL databases: https://addons.heroku.com

PS.  I'm guessing you used the default Heroku Postgres database - which populates DATABASE_URL with a [Heroku Postgres Starter Tier](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-starter-tier) database.

Comment: Hi @Jon, to be sure, I did 'heroku pg' and it showed app has no heroku-postgresql databases. I wonder if this is a bug in Heroku's celadon cedar stack.

Comment: If you don't have a free postgres database, then you don't have one.  That's not a bug.  If you want one, execute `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev`

Comment: Jon, thanks for the reply. What I meant was related to my original question. If I don't even have a postgre db in my add ons, yet I can see a postgre error in the heroku logs, it must be a heroku bug, particularly in the celadon cedar stack

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the DATABASE_URL variable to mysql database.

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxxxxx
```